# Good practice for method in java

Tags: java

I have a method that read from database and get some string there. According what I get I will override that string for another that I already know. For example:

- `str` → `string`
- `bin` → `binary`
- and so on..

My question is, what is the best practice for doing this? Of course I already thought about if's...

```
if (str.equals("str"))
    str = "string";
```

A file that have this things pre-defined, a multi-dimensional array, etc.. But this all seems a quite newbie, so what do you recommend? What is the best way?

Comment: What about a Map that you dynamically load

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a Map:

```
// create a map that maps abbreviated strings to their replacement text
Map<String, String> abbreviationMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

// populate the map with some values
abbreviationMap.put("str", "string");
abbreviationMap.put("bin", "binary");
abbreviationMap.put("txt", "text");

// get a string from the database and replace it with the value from the map
String fromDB = // get string from database
String fullText = abbreviationMap.get(fromDB);
```

You can [read more about Maps here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Comment: Thnks for answer,is really helpfull and for now will be my solution, However,i have to create a new code each time i have a new string for add..

Comment: You could also use a ResourceBundle or a Properties file or a static constructor in a utility class.  I would probably declare a static final map in some class to hold this info.  Actually, I would probably use a database to hold the abbreviations if at all possible.  You could read the data from the database into some map when your app gets initialized.

Comment: you can store all info in property file or xml-form file and when your app start or during runing get this info and form your map

Answer (score 2):

You could use a map, for example:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("str", "string");
map.put("bin", "binary");

// ...

String input = ...;
String output = map.get(input); // this could be null, if it doesn't exist in the map
```

Answer (score 1):

Map is a good option as people have suggested. The other option which I normally consider in this scenario is Enum. It gives you an additional capability of adding behavior for a combination.